# Responsive size of a JButton Icon

Tags: java, image, swing, icons

I am using the drag and drop system of netbeans to create my GUI.
I created a button and added an icon to it, my problem is that the image is to big for the size I want the button to be.

Is there any way of making this icon having the same size as the button?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way of making this icon having the same size as the button?

The size of the button is determined by the size of the Icon.

You can create a new `Image` by using the `Image.getScaledInstance(...)` method and then create an new `ImageIcon` from the scaled image.

Depending on your exact requirement and usage of layout managers, you might be able to use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will adjust the size of the image as the size of the button is changed.